# PHP and AJAX - make ajax call on load of a document

Tags: php, ajax

Can I make an AJAX call immediately after loading a page? To be more specific, I have an ajax action on click of some html tag (say in page 1). Now when I come to the same page (page 1) from some other page (say page 2), (i.e.. on ready of the document) can I make that ajax call which is present in the onclick of that appropriate html tag? I am using PHP as server side script..

There were confusion on my question.. Let me explain more.

I have an phtml page where there are lot of ajax calls on click of various tags. 
Lets say, tag1 has **send-message** functionality ajax call which on click loads a compose message part of html.
Similarly tag2 has photo display funcitonality ajax call which on click loads the photo display part of html. 
Now I'm in page 2 which is a search result page Where I have a link for page 1. That link is **send-message** link. So now I have to come to page 2 and with compose message part html loaded. I want to load it via ajax which will be performed on clik of the send-message link (tag 1)in page 1. How to accomplish this? How will I inform to page 1 to load the compose message part of html through ajax?

Comment: Bit confusing, is your data on the same HTML and you have different <DIV> tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call that function explain below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function_name();
</script>
```

Comment: This is fine sam. But I have edited my question. Can you take a look at it now?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what you want to achieve here but if you're asking if you could do AJAX on ready of the document, then i think you can..

Comment: i don't know if i understood you correctly. maybe you should specify more details? include your code perhaps..

Comment: If your data is in a seperate page, then just call it using ajax like you did in page 1.

but, if it is in the same page as page 1, then you have to do a work around for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Check this out in jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:g_site_path+'search/agentpopup',
        dataType:'html',
        data:data,
        success:function(html){
            $("#agentpopup").html(html);             
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Is the php data-feild that will tell from where the page request is coming (Ex. Page 2 has requested Page 1). Note that [HTTP-Referer](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is by its very nature risky and can easily be spoofed. To test for document ready, you can use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax('your_ajax_script.php', function(result) {
       /* Do what ever you want to do of result*/
          console.log(result);
   });
});
```